# Gradle: Emma: runtime controller could not be started, aborting & NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: gradle, easymock, emma

I have multiple failing tests in my gradle build due to Emma.

I am seeing these two errors:

```
java.lang.Error: EMMA: runtime controller could not be started, aborting
```

and

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.vladium.emma.rt.RT
```

Is there a resource anywhere that speaks to why this problem may occur? Another developer insists that this may be an issue between gradle and easymock.

Answer (score 0):

The error messages look like gradle can't find the emma jar.

Gradle works just fine with easymock in my experience. I even use gradle to build my [extension to easymock](https://github.com/fsparv/EasierMock). I usually use the [JaCoCo](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/) code coverage tool [built in to gradle](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html).

If you can't or don't want to switch to JaCoCo, perhaps try you might try using the [Emma plugin](http://wiki.gradle.org/display/GRADLE/Plugins#Plugins-Emmaplugin) although I cannot personally vouch for it since I use JaCoCo.

If the reason you can't switch is a draconian approval process for open source libraries that would apply to that plugin too (been there!), or that plugin doesn't work, then you might try this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'emma:emma:2.1.5320'
    }
}
```

If none of those work for you, then you will need to post specifics of your build and how you are invoking emma.